# Extract digits from bash variable

Tags: regex, bash, variables, digits

I have this code:

```
for a in `ls *w.txt`; do perl getSequenceNs.pl $a /home/prenos/medicago/${a:0:1}.NOLE.fas >sequences/${a}_sequence.txt; done
```

It has been working quite well unless I recognized, that ${a:0:1} extracts first digit from $a and unfortunately there are sometimes two.

So, my variable $a contains:

```
dsomeletters <-one digit and letters, for example 1.NOLE.fas

ddsomeletters <-two digits and letters, for example 12.NOLE.fas
```

How can I extract only digits? How should I modify my code (what should I use use instead of `${a:0:1}`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
${a//[^0-9]*}
```

should do what you want.  That is actually a bashism, so you might prefer the more portable:

```
${a%%[^0-9]*}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, don't parse `ls`, just the glob will do and properly handle ugly characters. Now then, you can use `bash` string manipulation a couple ways to get the number:

```
$ var=123abc456def
$ echo ${var%%[^0-9]*}
123
$ echo ${var//[^0-9]*/}
123
```

Note that `*` here is not the usual 0+ repetitions, it is globbing. Both patterns remove from the first character that is not a digit to the end of the string. So your final command should look like this:

```
for a in *w.txt; do perl getSequenceNs.pl "$a" /home/prenos/medicago/${a%%[^0-9]*}.NOLE.fas >"sequences/${a}_sequence.txt"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the letter portion of the filename always consistent? If so, you could avoid the problem by using `basename`:

```
NAME=`basename $a .NOLE.fas`
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am bash beginner, so my attempts to use this vere not succesfull.